# Machine worked for $100$ hours. Probability that it will work for another $500$ hours.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables, exponential-distribution

> In an engine factory the time of work of machines is a random variable
>   $X$. The random variable has an exponential distribution with
>   parameter $\lambda = \frac{1}{1000}$.
>
> It is known that the machine has already been working for $100$ hours.
>   What is the probability that it will be able to work for another $500$
>   hours?

How do I solve it? My attempt:

$P(X>500+100 | X = 100) = P(X > 600 | X = 100) = P(X > 500)$

This is how I started, by applying *memorylessness*.

Continuing:

$$P(X > 500) = \int_{500}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\frac{x}{\lambda}}dx$$

$$P(X > 500) = \int_{500}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{1000}} e^{-\frac{x}{\frac{1}{1000}}}dx$$

$$P(X > 500) = \int_{500}^{\infty} 1000 e^{-1000x}dx = \underbrace{\color{red}{\frac{1}{e^{500000}}}}_{\text{nonsense?}}$$

On the other hand, if I do this:

$$P(X > 500) = \int_{500}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1000} e^{-\frac{x}{1000}}dx \approx 0.60653$$ which seems like a more legitimate value.

Would anyone help me formalize my calculations? What was wrong with my formulas? Also, perhaps I should have used $\geq$ symbol instead of $>$ somewhere.

Comment: I would replace the initial equals in the conditional probability with a $\ge$. So, it would be: $$P(X>600|X\ge 100)$$ because $$P(X>600|X=100) = 0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "nonsense" answer is the result of using $\lambda$ as though assuming that $\lambda = \frac1{1000}$ means that the machine is expected to break after $\frac1{1000}$ hours. Clearly, the probability of it lasting for $500$ hours is quite low in that case.

Whether $\lambda$ represents the expected time until the first event, or the expected frequency of events, is a matter of convention. Which convention you follow will affect whether you should use $\lambda x$ or $\frac x\lambda$ in your integrals.

For continuous random variables, there is little difference between $>$ and $\geq$. So you can mostly use whichever you like.